# Shift+Ctrl+0 key combination not seen by application on Windows Vista

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, keyboard-events

I start with a new Delphi VCL application, add Menus to the uses clause, drop a label on the form, and assign the form's OnShortCut event:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Label1.Caption := ShortCutToText(ShortCut(Msg.CharCode, KeyDataToShiftState(Msg.KeyData)));
end;
```

On XP, this works correctly for all shortcut key combinations that I've tried, including <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.  On Vista and Windows 7, the test application displays <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, but not <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.  Other combinations like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, and even <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> are displayed fine.

Running the application under the debugger, I find that the OnShortCut event is never fired with Msg.CharCode = Ord('0') if both the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys are held down while the <kbd>0</kbd> key is pressed.

The Delphi IDE has the same problem under Vista.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> sets bookmark 1, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> does not set bookmark 0, which it should.

I've tested this with Delphi 2007 and 2010 on virgin installs of Windows Vista and 7 in VMware, so there's no 3rd party software trapping the keys.  I haven't tried any other development tools to determine if the problem is with Delphi or with Vista itself.

Comment: Very interesting I just reproduced the behaviour here on Vista with a Delphi 6 app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> is preassigned in Vista to the input method editor (IME) :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967893

This will solve your problem but will impact users of IMEs (mostly asian versions), so you should consider not using this shortcut.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Odd that my searches in Google and Bing didn't find this.  I guess the dumb part is that a clean install of Vista with US locale settings has only one keyboard layout and no IME and thus no need for a system-wide hotkey to switch between anything.

Comment: @Jan: perhaps it would be better if Google allowed Regex searches?  ;-)

Comment: Google search turns up this article. How to fix for Windows 7 though?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're not the first to ask this, I found [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/shiftctrl0-not-working-in-vista) thread on the How-To Geek Forums.

Then I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967893) MS knowledge base article:

"Input method editor keyboard shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>) switches the input language in Vista"

It is used to switch between languages. There is a workaround to turn this off. I just tried it and it works, the application now recognises <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

Comment: I found the howtogeek.com article before asking my question.  It only states the problem exists, but does not provide a practical solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try the old school <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to set bookmark 0.